# InDesign (CS4) Master Page Overrides

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs4, master-page

I have an InDesign document with master pages defined. I created the document and the masters. I have overrides allowed on several items on the master page, and have been able to alter them on a document page based upon the master, but when I attempt to change one of the master page items from "not allowed" to "allowed," I am unable to then override it. The other overrideables are still overridable ( :O ).

IIRC, I toggled other items and the changes are reflected properly in the document.

I don't have it here with me, but the one thing I have not done (I realize as I type this) is blow away the page and start fresh. I moved on quickly because I am billing and it is a non-profit.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you apply the master page to the document page more than once? sometimes I do that and end up with multiple instances of the same thing (e.g., a colored box) and the second instance is actually on top of the first, so when I delete it, it looks like it's still there (because I had two and didn't know it).

Comment: Is anything accidentally locked on the page?

Comment: I don't think it is locked: it is an image which I changed just prior to enabling the override. It is possible I applied it twice, but I have no memory of it: I actually copied a document I made a few months ago and removed content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test of whether it's some kind of glitch in the file itself (which it might be) is to export to IDML, then create a fresh INDD from the IDML file. This is good practice anyway to remove bloat and potential cruft in files you reuse, as the next higher gradient from "Save As."

Another quick check is to delete the item from the MP and see if it also disappears on the page. If it doesn't, you have a duplicate somewhere, as Lauren suggests.

I don't recall this as a reported bug in CS4, and I don't have CS4 currently installed on my machines to run some tests.

Comment: I never found a solution to this. I did try what you suggested. Everything else on the page is alterable except this item, and it is not locked. It is easily editable on the master page, but I just couldn't alter the one item on a normal page based upon the master. Obviously, I just used a manually added item to get the job done.

Comment: That *is* perplexing. Try bringing this up in the Adobe InDesign forums. Several heavy-hitter Adobe folks hang out there, and may have a definitive answer or might request the file for some forensics. The DOM, in theory, can't do what you're seeing, so it has to be a bug.